# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - Try to understand D3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, observablehq

I try to make this [code](https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph) works (D3.js). Basically, this code render a graph stored in json file.

But there is something I don't understand that may be obvious but I'm not able to get it.

I have this part of the code

```
color = {
    const scale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
    return d => scale(d.group);
}
```

Which throws the following error :

```
':' expected.

{
    "resource": "",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "1005",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "':' expected.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 5,
    "startColumn": 11,
    "endLineNumber": 5,
    "endColumn": 16
}
```

This color is used on this part of the code :

```
const node = svg.append("g")
        .attr("stroke", "#fff")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(nodes)
        .join("circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("fill", color)
        .call(drag(simulation));
```

I'm sure, it's something related to Javascript. Do you have any clues for me in order to understand that ?

Thank you

Comment: Your code is using the form of an object literal, but the contents are code. It fails because as of the space after `const`, you're violating the syntax of an object literal. I can't make out what you want `color` to be, but you need to either make it a function (so it can have code in it) or an object (with just properties and methods in it).

Comment: That's Observable, please read this: https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/observables-not-javascript.